# Using the sound card of a DVD player with a surround sound system for my monitor

Tags: audio, sound-card, hardware-rec, io

I've recently acquired a DVD player with a built-in 5+1 Surround sound system from a family member. I have been using streaming services quite awhile now so I really don't need a DVD player. However I still could use the sound system. It's pretty much new. The only problem is, since it is attached to the DVD player itself, I could only use it when I used the player. I don't want that. If possible I would like to use the sound system as speakers for my monitor or my TV. So I've taken out (hopefully the correct one) the sound card from the player. The machine seems to be working fine and I am getting audio from my TV, so no problem there. But what can I do with this sound card? Is there a way to make it work as an external adapter for my TV or my monitor? I would much appreciate if anyone could help me with this. I am sharing the sound card of the player below:

[image] [image]

<sup>Click for larger</sup>

Comment: I could provide additional pictures if needed.

Comment: How to bash some random electronics into acting as a "sound card" or even just a normal amplifier is not a problem with *computer* hardware or software. This is purely an electronics problem. If it had inputs from a computer and were intended to be used that way but for some reason didn't work then it might be on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a 'sound card' it's an analogue audio amplifier. Those cheap all-in-one 5.1-capable DVD players were never meant to play audio from any other source, so if you feed it at that point you're feeding the power amp, with no volume or EQ controls. You'd have to work that into your circuit earlier.

If you can figure out the pin-out of the ribbon cables [either by finding a service manual or by trial & error… which could be *loud*], you could feed it low-level 5.1, assuming you can get that from the computer. If you can't feed 5.1 directly from the computer without buying additional hardware, it would probably be cheaper & certainly easier to abandon this & just buy a cheap dedicated computer 5.1 system.